# How can we stream a rtmp url in react js?

Tags: reactjs, rtmp, react-player

I need to integrate RTMP player in my reactjs app.I'm getting rtmpUrl for streaming and tried with react player but it is not supporting rtmp url.

Comment: Rtmp in the browser requires flash.

Comment: Hi... Did you get this to work?? Kindly share the output which will be helpful for others